# Bug in Apple Mail's embedded retina image handling or my source?

Tags: image, macos, email, html-email

Think of a small (valid) html mail with an image. Litmus tests ran fine.

The images are downscaled to provide a sharp resolution on high DPI devices (a.k.a. Retina Images), i.e. the image is 500px wide but to be displayed at 250px.

When I send the mail with an embedded image instead of a remotely served image, I noticed a strange behavior in Apple Mail on macOS (tested on 10.12.6): The layout is broken.

Screenshot Remote:
[image: image from remote server]

Screenshot Embedded:
[image: image embedded via cid]

**As you can clearly see, when embedded the image breaks out of the table. This only happens if the real image size is larger than the current preview pane size.**

I simplified the example up to the point where I realized that this might be an Apple Bug. Does anybody know a Radar for this? Or a workaround?

I played with `overflow` etc but did not find a solution..

The bug does not occur when

- the image is @1, so it's exactly the same size as displayed (but not sharp enough on high DPI then)
- the preview pane is larger than the image file dimensions

It looks like Apple Mail uses the real dimension to fit it into the table when an image is embedded via `cid` or even `base64`. When served remotely it is downscaled first.

**Update**
Submitted as `rdar://33564090`, see https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5011843189833728.

**Source of test mail**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Apple Mail Retina Image Bug</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <p>
    Retina Image in Signature Test
    <br>
    Best regards,
    <br>
    </p>

    <!-- Footer with Retina Image -->

    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background: #eeeeee;">
    <tr>
        <td style="padding: 10px;">
            <!--img alt="Logo" src="http://via.placeholder.com/500x50" width="250" height="25" border="0" style="width: 250px; height: 25px;"-->
            <img alt="Logo" src="cid:logo" width="250" height="25" border="0" style="width: 250px; height: 25px;">
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried max width in the embedded image? One thing to note will be if you embed the image into the HTML, this will increase the file size. An increase in file size will mean gmail & yahoo clipping emails and can also mean deliverability issues .

Comment: @Syfer Yes, indeed I did. Even with max-width the issue remains. Regarding the size: You are absolutely correct. I am embedding small icons & a logo, color and size optimized to be less than 10 kb in total. Stripping limit with gmail is iirc 103 kb. Benefit of embedding: most mail clients will display the embedded images immediately without requiring clicking a "download image" button. Especially Outlook. But thanks for making people aware of this drawback!

Comment: Hi, I fix this with width: 100% to the image. But now I got a miss positioned image.